# nl2br() not working when displaying SQL results

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, nl2br

On my Joomla module, we are using the following code to get shouts from the database

```
function getShouts($number, $timezone, $message) {
    $shouts = array();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*')
    ->from('#__shoutbox')
    ->order('id DESC');
    $db->setQuery($query , 0 , $number);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $i=0;
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        $shouts[$i]->id = $row->id;
        $shouts[$i]->name = $row->name;
        $shouts[$i]->msg = $row->msg;
        $i++;
    }
    return $shouts;
}
```

and the following code to display it in the *default.php*

```
print stripslashes($shouts[$i]->msg);
```

However this is causing problems when someone wants to input something like the following:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

If they go onto a new line, the post displays like so after being submitted:

```
test line 1rntest line 2
```

So I did some research and realised I had to use `nl2br()` which I did as shown below:

```
print stripslashes(nl2br($shouts[$i]->msg));
```

however, it didn't seem to resolve the issue. I also tried creating another function in the helper to replace it using `preg_replace` but this didn't help either.

Can anyone explain why line breaking isn't working after adding `nl2br()` and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this way:

```
print nl2br(stripcslashes($shouts[$i]->msg));
```

Pay attention to the `stripcslashes()` function, but not `stripslashes()`

Or just:

```
print nl2br($shouts[$i]->msg);
```

**UPD:** `nl2br()` function replaces `\n` with `<br />`. The problem is that you don't have `\n` in your text, but have `n` or `\\n`. I think there is no need to use `stripslashes()` when you get data from base, except the situation when you have ecranized data in your base.